# I am creating a backend for eber website but in got his error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a backend for eber website but got an error
This is the code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
      BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

# Create your models here.

class  CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password = None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
           raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            
        
        )   
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user
     
    def create_superuser(self, email, password= None):
        user = self.create_user(
            
            email,
            password = password,
           )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
     
class  User(AbstractBaseUser):
    
    email = models.EmailField(
      verbose_name = 'email address',
      max_length = 255,
      unique = True,
    )            
    
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    #USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    
    def __str__(self):
       return self.email 
     
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj= None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        
        return True
        
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
           "Does the user have permissions to view the app?"
           return True
```

The error I got is this:

```
TypeError at /api/v1/users/
create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
Exception Location: /home/danish-khan/django_drf/eberbackend/apps/users/views.py, line 14, in create
Python Executable:  /home/danish-khan/django_drf/django/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/danish-khan/django_drf/eberbackend',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 23 Feb 2021 03:58:00 +0000
```

I have tried very much but can't fix this.
I am trying to create a user, superuser only by email as username.
I mean username is not required so this error occurs and can't be fixed.
I email will be used instead of username.
I want to fix this issue in simple easy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem once.
You just have to add this in your settings.py file and everything will work just fine.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.Users'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

Comment: Thanks i applied these three lines to seetings.py and it starts working.

Comment: Happy to help .

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are missing `username.

```
 user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password = password,
       )
```

you can update it like:

```
     user = self.create_user(
        username=username
        email,
        password = password,
       )
```

And similarly, you need to update in `create_user` method.

Also from the docs explicitly states the `UserManager` class assumes that you have both `username` and `email` fields. Since you don't, you would need to create your own `subclass` that defines the `create_user` method but doesn't expect a `username` parameter.

Comment: He doesn't want username for the user creation. Also he has already created a `CustomUserManager` class. This doesn't answer the question.